# WP_Query with rewind_posts creates duplicate titles

Tags: wp-query

I have a `WP_Query` with `rewind_posts` that I use to filter posts if they belong to a particular category. Basically, if any post belongs in a category with `First`, it goes to the top of the list.

The loop does that, the only problem is that it creates duplicate posts. The post that's in the `First` category is at the top and it's also with the rest of the group.

Example of my problem:

- Title - First
- Title 2
- Title 3
- Title - First
- Title 4
- Title 5

Any ideas on how to fix this? This is the code I'm using for the loop:

```
<?php $args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post-status',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array ('post-status-published')
    )
)
); $query = new WP_Query( $args );?>
<div class="container">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) {
while( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php if (in_category('First') ) { ?>
        <?php the_title();?><br />
    <?php }

}  // end first while loop 

rewind_posts(); // rewind loop so we can rerun it ?>

<?php while( $query->have_posts() ) { // Start second while loop
    $query->the_post(); ?>

     <?php if (in_category('Second') ) { ?>
        <?php the_title();?><br />
    <?php }

}  // end first while loop 

rewind_posts(); // rewind loop so we can rerun it ?>

<?php while( $query->have_posts() ) { // Start second while loop
    $query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_title();?><br />

<?php } // end second while loop

rewind_posts(); // rewind loop so we can rerun it

} // End your if statement ?>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here

- You are checking whether the main query returned any posts and then loop through the posts of your custom query
- `rewind_posts()` is wrongly used. By default, `rewind_posts()` rewinds the loop of the main query. You should rewind the posts of your custom query.
- Your last loop just basically loops through all the posts again and then displays them all
- If a post belongs to more than one term, you can have duplicates. Best to do a check to avoid those
- Your `tax_query` does not really make sense. In your loop you are checking terms from the default taxonomy `category` while you are querying posts from another custom taxonomy. Anyways, that is for you to think about

Lets look at a skeletal solution

```
$args = [
    // Your query parameters
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Test to see if you have posts from the custom query, not main query
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    // Create an array to avoid duplicates
    $duplicates = [];

    // Run the loop for the first time
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();

        if ( in_category( 'First' ) ) :
            // Display what you need
            the_title();

            // Save the post ID to avoid duplicates
            $duplicates[] = get_the_ID();

        endif;
    endwhile; // End your first loop

    $query->rewind_posts(); // Rewind the custom loop

    // Start the second loop
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();

            if ( in_category( 'Second' ) ) :
                // Make sure the post is not duplicated
                if ( in_array( get_the_ID(), $duplicates ) )
                    continue;

            // Post is not duplicate, display it
            the_title();

            // Save the post ID to $duplicates
            $duplicates[] = get_the_ID();

        endif;
    endwhile; // End second loop

    $query->rewind_posts(); // Rewind second custom loop          

    // Run your loop one more time
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();

            // Check if the post is already displayed, if so, skip it
            if ( in_array( get_the_ID(), $duplicates ) )
                continue;

            // Display the post
            the_title();

    endwhile; // Close the last loop
    wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset $post global
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The taxonomy is needed because I'm creating a page that changes based on the date and what posts are created in a date range. The code above gave me a white screen.

Comment: What errors are you getting, what PHP version are you using. I'm using short array syntax that is only available since PHP 5.4. Also note, as I stated, my code is just a skeleton and therefor not a copy and paste correct example

Comment: Unexpected if on `if ( $query->have_posts() ) :`

Comment: Code updated. I missed a `;`. I'm coding from a mobile device so expect some syntax errors.

Comment: Just found the error as well. Thanks for the help! You rock!

Comment: My pleasure, glad it is helpful. ;-)